# Broadcast onReciever calls multiple times and it giving Source not found exception

Tags: android, exception, broadcastreceiver, network-connection

When Wifi connection or Mobile data connection enabled I am notifying in my application.But my onReciever method calls multiple time and it's giving "Source not found exception".But in my logcat it's not printing any exceptions.While debuging time only I found that exception.In debuging time when onReciever method ends tat debuger returns "Source not found exception".

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    System.out.println("Network change reciever started");      
    String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
    Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

When onReciever calls my syso prints 4 times in logcat and toas cams 2,3 times.Why?

What is the problem in my code?

Manifest :

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.electrical.coc.nz.automaticserversync.NetworkChangeReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Update 1#

```
public class NetworkUtil {

public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;

public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (null != activeNetwork) {
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            return TYPE_WIFI;

        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            return TYPE_MOBILE;
    }
    return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
}

public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
    int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
    String status = null;
    if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
        status = "Internet connection enabled";
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
        status = "Internet connection enabled";
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
        status = "Internet connection disabled";
    }
    return status;
}
}
```

Comment: add the logcat detail

Comment: In my logcat nothing was printed but at the time of debuging debuger takes ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread$ReceiverData) line: 2436 
into this page and it's showing Source not found

Comment: 03-22 12:24:53.907: I/System.out(4298): Network change reciever started03-22 12:24:53.907: I/System.out(4298): Network change reciever started03-22 12:24:53.907: I/System.out(4298): Network change reciever started03-22 12:24:53.907: I/System.out(4298): Network change reciever started in my logcat when onReciever calls it's printing this msg four times

Answer (score 0):

Your various network connections (3G, WiFi) are likely all transitioning through different states and each firing a change event. You'll want to put some more logic in your receiver to determine the new network status. Check out [this page](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html) to learn more about it.

Comment: Yes,Exactly.I done this checking in NetworkUtil class.          String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context); when my onReciever call NetworkUtil class getting called and it's takes the status from that class those validation done in  getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) method.

Comment: Then I'm not sure I understand what problem you're needing help with.

Comment: Pls check my Update#1.Here I am adding my NetworkUtil class.You feel free once you integrate this code and put a debuger in onRecieve method and switch it off and on your wifi or mobile data connection your debuger comes into onReciever then you stepDown until onRecieve method ends.Now you understand what problem i am facing Please..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
if (null != activeNetwork && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {

isConnected() : Indicates whether network connectivity exists and it is possible to
establish connections and pass data.
Always call this before attempting to perform data transactions.
```

Check this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/cX_ySxvm-zc) which tells how to debug `Source not found exception`